# Setup SSL on 2-3 sites on mulitsite server

Tags: apache, ssl, https, shared-hosting

After installing SSL on some of the sites on multi-site server, I am facing issue with non-ssl site.
When user accidentally visit non-ssl site with https, browser shows domain mismatch error. When user ignore warning and click on proceed to site, its shows the content of ssl site but URL still shows the non-ssl site's URL.
Also for some of the non-ssl site the google crawl wrong URL which contain path of ssl site.

Let me explain the scenario. I have 1 server which have 5 sites A, B, C, D and E. Out of five 2 (Say C and D ) are secured with SSL.Both the sites are working properly without any issue. Now the problem with non-ssl sites ( Say A, B and E ). Here whenever user visit any of the site with https ( https://www.A.com) browser (chrome) shows error "Your connection is not private" and when I click on "Advanced" button, here browser says "This server could not prove that it is www.A.com; its security certificate is from C.com". and when I click on "Proceed" the next screen show content of C.com but URL is still A.com.

Some one please check and help.

Thanks,

Comment: Sorry, but your question is confusing. Why should ssl certificates be of any interest for a "non-ssl site"? And for ssl sites (accessed using the https protocol), why don't you simply examine the certificates? Either they are invalid or they do not match the host names. In either case you have to specify much more details in your question for us to be able to help.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the additional information. That indeed shows a completely different situation... You will only be able to _partly_ solve the issue, unless you use certificates for _all_ sites (hosts) which I would strongly recommend. What you can do is to redirect https requests to sites without a certificate to redirect to the not encrypted http variant by means of a simple redirection rule inside the host configuration. That will remove the warning _after_ that initial redirection. You will however _not_ be able to do anything about the initial warning without additional certificates.

Comment: Thanks  arkascha for help, I will check this ( I think I can use multi-domain SSL certificate)

Comment: Sure, wildcard certificates (for multiple host names inside a single domain) cost around 10 Euros per year. An obvious alternative are the "Let's encrpt" certificates. which are indeed free of cost for as many domains / host names as you like, though the application is a bit different to what you might be used to.